# Shortening VSTS releases for ASP.NET Core SCD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, self-contained

I've got a basic ASP.NET Core web application with automated deployments running via VSTS. I was very surprised to receive an email just now telling me that my free Hosted Pipeline's allowance for this month has expired (4 hours total!).
That's fine, only have about a week to wait.

The release definition itself is simple - stop site, clear remote directory, FTP upload, start site.

My main problem is that a full release takes about 10-15 minutes due to the hosting platform requiring a self-contained deployment. As a result, the vast majority of the FTP upload time is spent uploading the .NET Core binaries one-by-one, most of which I'm fairly sure the application is not actually using - the application itself is tiny.

Is there any way I can cut down which binaries are included in this self-contained deployment? Otherwise I fear I might use up my release allowance more often.

It is also worth noting that the .NET Core restore step is the most time-consuming part of the build definition as well, but I am not sure if this is related or not.

Comment: What're tasks of the build/release definition? Can you share the detail build log here?

Comment: Add/set system.debug to true, then start release and post the detail log here, you also can share the log file on the OneDrive.

Comment: Will have to wait until the 1st of September before I can post that. Is that a variable that I set somewhere?

Comment: You can setup a [private build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows), then queue build with this agent. On the other hand, you can share the previous build log here.